# Rank of the matrix of parallel planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

**Using the definition of RANK here:** [rank of matrix](http://stattrek.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-rank.aspx)

It is the maximum number of linearly independent row vectors.

We have that $\langle a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}\rangle$ is a normal vector for $P_1$ and likewise with the other column vectors.

Since these arent parallel, then why isn't the rank $ = 3$, since there are 3 linearly independent vectors?

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is 3, then the system of equations always has a solution so planes meets at a unique point.

Comment: @HanulJeon, then why does it not follow the definition?

Comment: Your intuition works only if the number of vectors is 2. For example, consider $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are not parallel and not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your title for this question. The three planes are distinctly *not* parallel. Three parallel planes would be like three floors of a building, one above the other, not meeting.

A simple example would be the three planes $z = 0 \ ; z = 1 \ ; z = 2 .$
In this case $$A = \pmatrix{0&0&1 \\0&0&1\\0&0&1}$$
which has rank 1.

The planes shown each intersect the others, pairwise, but there is no unique point of intersection, and no shared line of intersection, not like the above.

---

If rank A = 3 with no free variables, there would be a single unique point of intersection, so rank A is not 3. 
The simplest example to visualize this case it the three coordinate planes
$z = 0 \ ; y = 0 \ ; x = 0 \ $.
Here A is the identity matrix 
$$A = \pmatrix{1&0&0 \\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$
and rank A = 3

If rank A = 2 there is one free variable so there would be a single one-dimensional intersection, a line. If the b's are all zero or otherwise consistent the planes would meet like the pages of a book.
An example would be $ z = 0 \ ;  y = 0 \ ; \ y + z = 0$

This gives the matrix 
$$A = \pmatrix{0&1&1 \\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$

We can reduce this easily and we see rank A = 2

A change in the b's will make an inconsistent system so that the planes intersect pairwise as in the given diagram, but there is no point that is a solution to all three equations simultaneously.

The system $ z = 0 \ ;  y = 0  \ y + z = 1$ will give a graph of the form given.

Therefore rank A = 2

---

Just to be complete: If rank A = 1, there are two free variables, so there is a two-dimensional solution, and in fact there is only one plane with the others coincident if the b's are zero or consistent, parallel planes otherwise